# Adding more than margin of 5 in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, padding, margin

in bootstrap, we can add margin from 0-5 but I want to add more margin using bootstrap ,
I tried the following m-8 but it's not working

Comment: `m-8` is not available, if you want `m-8` then you need to make class, or inline css,  like `margin : 6rem;`

Answer (score 1):

You can add new spacer definitions to the $spacers variable, use your own custom.scss for that, like so:

```
// 1. import bootstrap's variables to override them
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

// 2. your overrides
$spacers: (
  0: 0,
  1: ($spacer * .25),
  2: ($spacer * .5),
  3: $spacer,
  4: ($spacer * 1.5),
  5: ($spacer * 3),
  6: ($spacer * 5)
)

// 3. bootstrap and its default variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

basically anything you can find in _variables.scss that's relevant for you, you can override.

see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125059/3584353

and about overriding bootstrap variables here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

Comment: Works for me in bootstrap 5, but webpack throws an error, when I only add additional definitions without including the original spacers. To avoid this, include the original spacers 0-5 in the override.